# How to slide an element without removing it from DOM ( A psudo slide maybe)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I've been struggling for this problem almost a month with no success.

Consider I have a button and and element in the DOM ( like an Image or ...) ,

When I hit this button , The element must slide(left or right) . So far this is easy.

```
        $(button).on('click',function(){
           $('mySlidingElement').slideToTheLeft();
           // consider this works fine .
        });
```

**But I dont want that element to be disappeard** !!

Like this Picture:

You see the image is sliding to the right , but I doesn't disappear. and it seems there are two of this picture !!!!!!!

Like I want to show an psudo or fake sliding effect .

I can use 2 Images  and then slide the front one . this will work. But I dont want to do this .

[image: SLide to right]

I didnt know how to ask this question and if my question is not right , please forgive me:(

NOTE : I'm using angularjs and jquery , my slide animation is based on adding and removing css classes/

Thanks a lot

Comment: you have to have two images for that

Comment: There is no way without having two image ?

Comment: two image tags, you can clone a single one with script though to make the second one

Comment: @xe4me:Check the answer below and do let me know if some improvement required

Comment: A small example using the two images idea, and jQuery's animate function: http://jsfiddle.net/52et8/ (click on the image). Is this what you're after?

Comment: @charlietfl , Can you give a an example or a source explanation of cloning ? 
I think this is the only way (clone);

Comment: @StathisG , Thanks a lot , but like I said , I cant use the same element twice , because actually this is not an Image , its a grid with lots of collumns and rows , so it's not a good performance to use it twice

Comment: here's a crude clone demo that does a bit of what you want http://jsfiddle.net/G4Asy/1

Comment: @charlietfl

Thankkkkkkkkssssssssssssssssssss
This is exactly what I want
I'm going to use it :P
you are a genius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this solves your requirement :)

html

```
<div id="static"></div>
```

css

```
    * {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0;
}
#static {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:tomato;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
#static::after {
    content:"";
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:orange;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
    opacity:0;
}
#static.plsSlide::after {
    content:"";
    left:100px;
    opacity:1;
}
```

jquery

```
$("#static").click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass("plsSlide");
```

});

I have used colours instead of images.Please set the image as a background to this `div`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/7EznA/2/)

Comment: This works fine
But the actual problem is that specific element which I want to slide it , is a grid with lots of columns , 
So I think the only way of achieving this , is to clone that object ,
But I dont know how